# use for loop to add elements to an existing dictionary in a list

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
d = [{'Sport': 'MLB', 'Position': 'SP', 'Age': '25'},
     {'Sport': 'NBA', 'Position': 'PG', 'Age': '28'}]
```

I have another list that i would like to append to the above by using a for loop:

```
c = [{'2015 Salary' : '25'}, {'2015 Salary': '35'},
    {'2016 Salary' : '30'}, {'2016 Salary' : '40'}]
```

I would like the final output to be

```
e = [{'Sport': 'MLB', 'Position': 'SP', 'Age': '25', '2015 Salary': '25',  
     '2016 Salary': '30'},
     {'Sport': 'NBA', 'Position': 'PG', 'Age': '28', '2015 Salary': '35',  
     '2016 Salary': '40'}}]
```

The positions would always be the same thats why i was going to use a for loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to repeat over `d` while updating from `c`.

```
import itertools

for existing, new_dict in zip(cycle(d), c):
    existing.update(new_dict)
```

`cycle` turns a list into an infinite list by restarting from the beginning whenever it is exhausted. When you zip them together, `cycle(d)` and `c` pair up to give:

```
({'Sport': 'MLB', 'Position': 'SP', 'Age': '25'}, {' 2015 Salary' : '25'})
({'Sport': 'NBA', 'Position': 'PG', 'Age': '28'}, {'2015 Salary': '35'})
({'Sport': 'MLB', 'Position': 'SP', 'Age': '25'}, {'2016 Salary ': '30'})
({'Sport': 'NBA', 'Position': 'PG', 'Age': '28'}, {'2016 Salary' : '40'})
```

Which then update `d` to your expected output.

Comment: i wouldnt want to create 2 new dictionaries tho, i would only want 2 total.

Comment: @skimchi1993 I'm not sure what that means. No new dictionaries are being created here. `d` is being updated in-place.

Comment: @skimchi1993 Those four lines in the end are just the pairings, not the resulting list of dicts.

Comment: @tobias_k OH! I can see how that's confusing, let me edit it to be a bit clearer (good catch)

Comment: @AdamSmith, I didn't know about the `cycle` function. This is a very impressive answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by:

```
for i, current_d in enumerate(d):
    current_l = c[i::2]
    for e in current_l:
        current_d.update(e)
```

`d` will contain the information that you want.

Comment: This does not work because c is a longer list than d, and it only adds the 2015 salaries

Comment: @MxieBall, I agree with you. I hope the one who asked the question updates it.

Comment: in my case, they wont be hte same length, is this not possible then?

Comment: After the edit this still only adds the 2015 salaries

Comment: @skimchi1993, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help

```
for i in range(len(d)):
     for j in range(i,len(c),i+2):
             d[i].update(c[j])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my one-line style solution using **comprehensions**, without any needed import, and which works also whatever the length of `d` input:

```
d = [{'Sport': 'MLB', 'Position': 'SP', 'Age': '25'},
     {'Sport': 'NBA', 'Position': 'PG', 'Age': '28'}]

c = [{'2015 Salary': '25'}, {'2015 Salary': '35'},
     {'2016 Salary': '30'}, {'2016 Salary': '40'}]

result = [{k:v for i in ([d[j]] + c[j::len(d)]) for k,v in i.items()} for j in range(len(d))]

print(result)
# [{'Sport': 'MLB', 'Position': 'SP', 'Age': '25', '2015 Salary': '25', '2016 Salary': '30'},
#  {'Sport': 'NBA', 'Position': 'PG', 'Age': '28', '2015 Salary': '35', '2016 Salary': '40'}]
```